# Error in LocalHost, IE cant show the web page

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7

I have one problem, when I go to my IE and I write localhost the IE show this message "Internet Explorer can't show the web page". one week ago I requested localhost and this message did not appeared. only show the IIS 7 image (work good).

I reinstall the IIS and nothing.

Comment: Do you have skype on the machine you have iis?

Comment: I havent skype becouse the problem is on my work´s pc, and here not let install this program, i have the iss installed. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your IIS manager and make sure that the **Default Web Site** under the Sites folder, and **DefaultAppPool** under Application Pools are started.

Comment: All is ok, how you said. but the url localhost dont work.. Thanks for your help

Comment: is your Default Web Site configured to use port 80? what have changed since the last time it worked?

Comment: yes the default port is 80, i did nothing special, i remember was that the windows got crahs and the pc restarting, after the video driver fail and i saw that localhost dont works. tanks sorry for my English.

Comment: Is the World Wide Web Publishing Service running?

Comment: Yes, the wwwService is running. I read on one page that could be that the iss file got corrupted, solution reinstall the IIS. Thank for your help pinoy_ISF.